# working with .Document.getElementById() and variables in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select the value from a dropdown box using vba, the code block for the dropdown box is as follows

```
<input type="text" id="form_autocomplete_input-1542902425322" list="form_autocomplete_suggestions-1542902425322" placeholder="Search keyword or select filter" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="form_autocomplete_suggestions-1542902425322 form_autocomplete_selection-1542902425322">
```

If the value of `form_autocomplete_suggestions-1542902425322` was static I would use `.Document.getElementById("form_autocomplete_suggestions-1542902425322").Value = "Role: Student"` however this seems to be a randomly generated numerical value.

I have had a look and it seems I cannot simply add a wildcard in such as `.Document.getElementById("form_autocomplete_suggestions-*").Value = "Role: Student"`

And as its randomly generated and such a long number it cannot loop through an array of values. so I am unsure on how to solve this issue.

Comment: So how many text boxes will there be on the form?  You dont have to loop through the array of numbers, you can look at the options on offer beginning with `.getElements` etc, to get them to a collection and loop those if neccessary.  Can you explain a little more in numbers of objects, or paste a screen shot of the page.?

Comment: Hi, not sure what you mean by form? the problem is that the value of the dropdown box changes 
![image](https://i.imgur.com/zhoFoaG.png)
So I cannot use `.Document.getElementById("form_autocomplete_suggestions-1542902425322").Value = "Role: Student"`
as the value of 1542902425322 has now changed to something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css attribute equals value selector syntax with the `^` operator to say starts with a certain substring. You could also use `*` instead, which means contains.

```
[id^='form_autocomplete_input-']
```

**VBA:**

```
ie.document.querySelector("[id^='form_autocomplete_input-']")
```

---

You might also use:

```
[placeholder='Search keyword or select filter']
```

Which would be:

```
ie.document.querySelector("[placeholder='Search keyword or select filter']")
```

---

As you indicate this needs to be selected you may need:

```
ie.document.querySelector("[id^='form_autocomplete_input-']").Selected = True
```

---

**Reference:**

1. [CSS attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: Did you try this?